# How to bind multiple property in xaml for label control in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two property `TotalWeightInGrams` and `TotalWeightInKiloGrams`, i want to bind in label control as following `output`

```
string format="{0} ({1} Kgs)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to make a new property that returns the string you want and bind to that. This way you don't need to do anything more complicated and can change the formatting in code if needed.

Comment: Thanks Sami, Can i know how to do it xaml?

Comment: In WPF, i did using multiple bindings but it is not working in xamarin xaml page

Comment: @RiyasAhamed As far as I know it's not supported on Xamarin